# MVC Partial Views - Why isn't my controller method getting called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been working with MVC for quite a long time, but, until now, have never used partial views. So I'm a bit unclear as to what's going on. I have this HTML in my 'parent' page:

```
@model MyApp.Entities.HomePage

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" id="searchTags" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." autofocus="autofocus">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    @Html.Partial("_itemList", Model, new ViewDataDictionary {{"searchTag", "Heath"}});
</div>
```

As you can see, the home page is including the _itemList partial view. In my controller code, I have this:

```
    public ActionResult _itemList(string searchTag)
    {
        return this.PartialView();
    }
```

When the parent page loads, this controller method, for the partial view, is not getting called. However, the partial page, which displays some images, does render. I'm wondering why the partial page controller method isn't getting called?

Comment: To call a child action, you need `@Html.Action("_itemList" ....)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Do you mean instead of @Html.Partial(...)?

Comment: Yes. `@Html.Partial()` will render the partial, as opposed to `@Html.Action()` which will call the method and return its result (in this case the same partial)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - That worked. Thank you. If you enter this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Zoltan has already added it, so accept that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Html.Partial` directly renders a partial view with the passed model (optionally). I mean directly that it's not going though the MVC lifecycle, only acts like rendering a "template".

If you want to run a **child action**, which **is** going through the entire lifecycle (acts like a real request) then use `Html.Action` method. This way your controller action will be invoked, including the routing system, filters, etc.

One should consider which method he should use, because the Html.Action is much slower of course (even if most likely the bottleneck will not be here). I used to think this way: for reusing views use `Html.Partial`, for reusing both **business logic and view** use `Html.Action`.